# Two factor registration with react and php api

Tags: api, reactjs, two-factor-authentication

What is the proper way to do two factor registration when dealing with api?

1) On frontend there is a form - email and phone - sending data to api method

2) I have an API that register user, by email and phone, generate code and send it over sms on phone

Question - what is the proper way to check sms code on front? (send code as response for register looking not so secure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the flow should be (more or less):

```
client:
- user fills out form and hits submit
- sends form data to backend
- show field for 2FA code entry

server:
- handles form data, generates a 2FA code, and sends that code to the client via email and/or SMS
- store that code in a DB (relational or not, doesn't really matter); you could even just store it whatever session manager you're using
- map that code to the current session, or supply that code to the client to correlate the 2FA code to the client
```

the user receives the code

```
client:
- user enters the code and hits submit
- sends entered code to the server

server:
- using the session or the DB, validates the code
- then, and only then, you auth the user
```

You're right - never validate auth on the frontend.

Your basic code should look like this on the frontend:

```
class TwoFactorAuth extends React.Component {
    state = { stage: 1 };

    onSubmitStageOne = (data) => {
        // goes to /
        submit(data).then(() => {
            this.setState({ stage: 2 });
        });
    }

    onSubmitStageTwo = (data) => {
        // goes to /auth
        authenticate(data).then(() => {
            // success
        }).catch(() => {
            // wrong code, try again
        });
    }

    renderStageOne() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitStageOne}>
                <input name="email" />
                <input name="phone" />
            </form>
        )
    }

    renderStageTwo() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitStageTwo}>
                <input name="code" />
            </form>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.stage === 1 ? 
            this.renderStageOne() : 
            this.renderStageTwo(); 
    }
}
```

something to note is that I'm using ES6 classes and ES7 class property initializers - you'll need babel if you want to copy/paste the code above.

your backend routes would be *similar* to:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const code = utils.generate2FACode();
    request.session["code"] = code;

    utils.emailOrSMSUser(code);

    res.sendStatus(200);
});

router.post("/auth", (req, res) => {
    const code = req.session["code"];
    if (code === req.body.code) {
        req.session["signedIn"] = true; // simplified for demonstration
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
```

here I'm using `express` and `express-session`. I'll let you write `generate2FACode` and `emailOrSMSUser`.

edit: whoops, you said PHP API in the title - similar logic, just with PHP instead of Node/Express.